# Application of Gramian Angular Field to financial series?

Tags: time-series

I found this method to represent time series to improve performance of some ML models, any thoughts about this method? some applications or use cases in financial markets?

Comment: Would you kindly elaborate on Gramian Angular Field? Perhaps, add a link to the Wikipedia page or other references?

Comment: Sure, https://pyts.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/image.html#gramian-angular-field https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.00327.pdf

Comment: Represent time series in a polar coordinate system instead of the typical Cartesian coordinates. In the Gramian matrix, each element is actually the cosine of the summation of angles. from - Imaging Time-Series to Improve Classification and Imputation
Zhiguang Wang and Tim Oates